# Resolving Django URLs with many trailing slashes - development vs. production inconsistency

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-urls

I have a Python+Django website working under control of uWSGI and NginX.

On the production environment, each of the addresses below directs to an article. `APPEND_SLASH=True` setting makes the first URL (non-slash) redirect to the second URL (with one slash) - this is the part which I understand.

**What is making third, fourth and every each URL with any number of slashes working?**

```
1. http://example.com/my-article-slug
2. http://example.com/my-article-slug/
3. http://example.com/my-article-slug//
4. http://example.com/my-article-slug///
5. ...
```

URLs with many slashes just resolve the Django View (`ArticleDetail`) properly and show the article, without redirect (!).

However, on the Django local development web server, only first two of above links works. `Http404` is returned if URL has more than one slash.

The `DEBUG` setting has nothing to do with this issue, according to my investigation.

It is worth noting that this behavior is a problem when I want to resolve a Django View from an URI, because addresses with many trailing slashes work correctly (on the production), but they are not resolved correctly by `django.urls.resolve`:

```py
>>> from django.urls import resolve
>>> resolve('/my-article-slug/')
ResolverMatch(func=articles.views.ArticleDetail, args=(), kwargs={'slug': 'my-article-slug'}...
>>> resolve('/my-article-slug//')
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404...
```

**Django URLs cofiguration**:

```py
# urls.py
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('articles.urls')),
]

# articles/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from articles.views import ArticleDetail

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<slug:slug>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    ...
]
```

By the way, I've noticed that it is quite common behavior, i.e.:

> https://www.djangoproject.com////////////
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0////////////
>   https://www.dropbox.com////////////
>   https://www.dropbox.com/individual////////////
>   https://www.quora.com////////////
>   https://www.quora.com/answer////////////

Perhaps is it NginX-related issue?

Comment: That looks like it's nginx-related. Somehow your web server is removing the trailing multiple slashes before proxy-passing to your app server. You should investigate further and remove this behavior.